# Where to break a line when writing method?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I just learn retrofit and I just realize that when creating the retrofit api interface some of my endpoint call is very long. I want to know where to break to a new line so I can improve the readability of the code.

For example I have this code:

```
@POST("/login")
Observable<ResponseBody> postFormData(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password, @Field("first_name")String firstName, @Field("last_name")String lastName, @Field("email")String email);
```

Do I only need to break each parameter to new line or I also need to move the function name to below the function return type?

Comment: Pass a `Map` of fields instead . Use `@FieldMap Map<String,String> fields` as parameter of interface  method .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing it like this:

```
@POST("/login")
Observable<ResponseBody> postFormData(
      @Field("username") String username, 
      @Field("password") String password, 
      @Field("first_name") String firstName, 
      @Field("last_name") String lastName, 
      @Field("email") String email
);
```

but this is my personal opinion. It all depends on the way you like your code to look like. Another option is to pass `@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> fields` to limit the number of parameters